# preserve int64 values when parsing json in Go

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm processing a json POST in Go that contains an array of objects containing 64bit integers. When using json.Unmarshal these values seem to be converted to a float64 which isn't very helpful.

```
body := []byte(`{"tags":[{"id":4418489049307132905},{"id":4418489049307132906}]}`)

var dat map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

tags := dat["tags"].([]interface{})

for i, tag := range tags {

    fmt.Println("tag: ", i, " id: ", tag.(map[string]interface{})["id"].(int64))

}
```

Is there any way to preserve the original int64 in the output of json.Unmarshal?

[Go Playground of above code](https://play.golang.org/p/KA0YZ-eVgH)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can use a [Decoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) and [UseNumber](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.UseNumber) to decode your numbers without loss :

The `Number` type is defined like this :

```
// A Number represents a JSON number literal.
type Number string
```

which means you can easily convert it :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    body := []byte("{\"tags\":[{\"id\":4418489049307132905},{\"id\":4418489049307132906}]}")
    dat := make(map[string]interface{})
    d := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    d.UseNumber()
    if err := d.Decode(&dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tags := dat["tags"].([]interface{})
    n := tags[0].(map[string]interface{})["id"].(json.Number)
    i64, _ := strconv.ParseUint(string(n), 10, 64)
    fmt.Println(i64) // prints 4418489049307132905
}
```

**Solution 2**

You can also decode into a specific structure tailored to your needs :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Tags []map[string]uint64 // "tags"
}

func main() {
    body := []byte("{\"tags\":[{\"id\":4418489049307132905},{\"id\":4418489049307132906}]}")
    var a A
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &a); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a.Tags[0]["id"]) // logs 4418489049307132905
}
```

Personally I generally prefer this solution which feels more structured and easier to maintain.

**Caution**

A small note if you use JSON because your application is partly in JavaScript : JavaScript has no 64 bits integers but only one number type, which is the IEEE754 double precision float. So you wouldn't be able to parse this JSON in JavaScript without loss using the standard parsing function.

Answer (score 0):

easier one:

```
body := []byte(`{"tags":[{"id":4418489049307132905},{"id":4418489049307132906}]}`)

var dat map[string]interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

tags := dat["tags"].([]interface{})

for i, tag := range tags {
    fmt.Printf("tag: %v, id: %.0f", i, tag.(map[string]interface{})["id"].(float64))
}
```

Comment: The output is wrong with this solution, since both ids are changed to 4418489049307132928.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very old, but this is the solution I ended up using

```
/* 
   skipping previous code, this is just converting the float 
   to an int, if the value is the same with or without what's 
   after the decimal points
*/

f := tag.(map[string]interface{})["id"].(float64)
if math.Floor(f) == f {
  fmt.Println("int tag: ", i, " id: ", int64(f))    
} else {
  fmt.Println("tag: ", i, " id: ", f)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have run into this situation several times recently, to simplify the parsing code here, I just add a simple function to solve this problem.

Here is a runnable example, only one line of your code need to be replaced:
playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Gi8mxssUrVP

```golang
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"

    "github.com/sleagon/g"
)

func main() {
    val := `{"a": 9223372036854775807, "b": 1.2345}`
    data := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(val), g.Ptr(g.JMap(data)))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(data["a"]) // => 9223372036854775807 (int64)
}
```

You can find more information here: https://github.com/sleagon/g/pull/1