# How are "long" type integers handled in Hyperledger Composer transaction processor functions?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

When defining a Hyperledger Composer model, fields can be designated to have the type `long`, which is implemented as an `int64`.

How are `long` values passed onto transaction processor functions, when `int64` is not natively supported by Node.js? Is it converted to a `Number`? If so, wouldn't that mean that it is effectively downgraded to 52 bits of precision?

Comment: model data is passed in json format and parsed by node.js so it will be whatever node.js supports. I suspect you are looking at the GoLang generator that creates a representation of the model in GoLang ? int64 being the closed representation to a node.js number

Comment: @david_k I am specifically referring to the `long` format mentioned in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [preserve int64 values when parsing json in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946306/preserve-int64-values-when-parsing-json-in-go), it would seem that even if it is stored internally as an `int64` and serialized into JSON from golang as such, Node.js would indeed parse this into a regular `Number` thereby losing precision.